Sensitivity label works in Outlook web app but not desktop app
We are currently using M365 Business Premium licence and hence are using Azure Information Protection Premium Plan 1. We created an 'Internal' sensitivity label on compliance.microsoft.com, with "assign permissions now" configuration granting co-author access to all users and groups within the organisation . The label is working in the user's Outlook web app. However, when drafting a new email in Outlook desktop app, the option to select the label is there, but when I click on the label itself it reverts back to "no label".
All the users to which label policy is scoped can see the Label. but can't apply it. Some insights:

If I create a label with "Let users assign permission" configuration and then select the "Encrypt-Only" or "Do-Not-Forward" options. Then users can see that label and apply it in the Outlook desktop app and web.

If I create labels with "Assign Permission now" configuration, scope it to both file and email, grant co-author access to 'Authenticated Users', or 'all users and groups within the organisation', then users can select the label in Word/Excel etc, but not Outlook Desktop app. They can assign the same label in Outlook Web though. We are on the latest  - Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2403 Build 16.0.17425.20176) 64-bit. We use built-in labels by Office apps and never used AIP unified labelling client or the classic client.



We were able to fix it by deleting the mip folder in Outlook so it pulls the new template down. That being said, it still affects new users and it is not feasible to continually delete this folder for each user.
The mip folder is: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Outlook\MIPSDK\mip
This is occurring for Exchange Online and seems to only affect the newer versions of Office (i.e. Semi Annual does not have this issue).

This issue could be due to a few reasons. Here are some potential solutions:

Please Verify that the user account that’s signed into Outlook is a Microsoft 365 subscriber (File > Office Account).
The appropriate licenses must be assigned to the user for sensitivity labeling to be enabled.
In Outlook, the Sensitivity button automatically adjusts to show sensitivity labels corresponding to the From account.
A similar thread mentioned that Deletion and recreation of all labels
and policies might solve the issue.


Thank you for your response. Yes those basic steps have been done multiple times and waited for 72-96 hours sometimes for it to propagate, but still not resolved. The link you mentioned is for the old AIP unified labelling client. We use built-in labels in M365 Apps. All user accounts have correct licence assigned via the subscription. They are able to select the labels in Outlook Desktop where the label has a user defined permission that is Encrypt-Only or Do-Not-Forward.

The only ones they cannot select is where the permission is done using "Assign permissions now"  in the portal compliance.microsoft.com, with "All users and group within the organisation" having Co-Owner access. Please do note that they can select these labels on files and on emails in Outlook Web. It is just not working on Outlook Desktop client. There has been an progress on this using the ComplianceUtility Tool available here. I have opened a new issue there, in case you are interested
https://github.com/microsoft/ComplianceUtility/issues/3
